# Why doesn't Range.Formula work on cross-worksheet formulae?

Tags: excel, vba

The following line results in an "application-defined or object-defined error":

```
Sheet1.Range("B4").Formula = "=""Plutonium Resale Revenues""!K19"
```

Excel 2010.

Comment: Use this: Sheet1.Range("B4").Formula = "='Plutonium Resale Revenues'!K19" Since the sheet name has space, you need to put single quote around the worksheet name.

Comment: @Vikas Whats the output in B4 ? Can you try with any dummy example and then run my code and see what the difference.

Comment: Santosh, I know your code will work. I didn't say your code will not. As a good practice, copy should be avoided unless it is not the only solution. Just a thought, no offence to your answer though, it will definitely work. I believe, we first need to tell, that why his code is not working. And that is what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Sheet1.Range("B4").Formula = "='Plutonium Resale Revenues'!K19"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you want to copy formula from sheet Plutonium Resale Revenues K19 to Sheet1 B4.

```
Sheets("Plutonium Resale Revenues").Range("K19").Copy
Sheets("sheet1").Range("B4").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
Application.CutCopyMode=False
```

Comment: It certainly will work, but as a good practice, Copy should be used only when it is required. So I would rather prefer to fix his code.